# Изменение размеров окна при нестандартном интерфейсе

Tags: c, winapi

Делаю программу с нестандартным интерфейсом. Текущая задача - реализовать возможность мышью менять размер окна.
Пришла в голову такая идея - сделать регионы, совпадающие с рамками окна, и если над таким регионом наводится курсор, ЛКМ нажата, то движения мыши меняют размер окна.
Это хорошая идея, или можно что-то получше придумать?
Пишу на Си, использую только WinAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Идея хорошая, но какими средствами Вы ее собираетесь реализовывать?

Я могу предложить такой вариант:

1. перехватываем `WM_NCHITTEST`,
2. определяем, что курсор мыши находится на границе региона,
3. строим нормаль к его касательной в этой точке
4. и делаем ее приближение к одной из осей (left, right, top, bottom, left-top, left-bottom, right-top, right-bottom)
5. в зависимости от того, к какой оси было сделано приближение - возвращаем из `WM_NCHITTEST` результат, минуя `DefWindowProc`: `HTLEFT`, `HTRIGHT`, `HTTOP`, `HTBOTTOM`, `HTTOPLEFT`, `HTBOTTOMLEFT`, `HTTOPRIGHT`, `HTBOTTOMRIGHT`

Остальное, по идее, должна сделать `ОС`.